# in this function correct pointer not returned to the calling function

Tags: c, pointers, scope, dynamic-memory-allocation, singly-linked-list

the problem is when i print the list after deleting the node the printing function prints 0 in place of the deleted node.....but i wanted it to print nothing.

```
// the function call is delete_from_key(&head,i);
//node is struct linked_list
void delete_from_key(node *head, int key)
{
    node *new, *temp;
    if(head == NULL)
    {
        printf("nothing to delete . the list is empty.\n");
        return;
    }
    else if(head->num == key)
    {
        temp=head;
        head=temp->next;
        free(temp);
        return;
    }
    new=search_key(head, key);//search_key returns pointer node holding the key.
    if(new != NULL)
    {
        temp = new;
        new = new->next;
        free(temp);
        return;
    }
}
```

example:

the list is `1-> 2-> 3-> 4-> 5->`
if i called this function with key 2
the expected output is  `1-> 3-> 4-> 5->`
instead the actual output is `1-> 0-> 3-> 4-> 5->`

Comment: Don'e spam tags. `new` is a keyword in C++, so there is no possible way this is part of a C++ program. Tags are to define the scope of a question correctly, not to gain exposure.

Comment: `temp = new->next; //temp points to node holding the key`...`new->next = temp->next; //new->next points to node which is after the node holding the key`....`free(temp);`

Comment: You have missed setting the previous pointer of `new` to next pointer of `new` when `new` is not `NULL`. You have to keep track of previous pointer of the node which you want to delete.

Comment: @sameerkn don't answer in comments.

Comment: You have already checked if head is NULL in first if, so you don't need to check again in second...

Comment: Your function has more serious problem than that. What if you need to delete the head node? Will it work? Create a list with a single element and try to delete it.

Answer (score 4):

You need to update the previous node's `next` as well as it's `next` is getting deleted.

```
prev_node=search_key(head, key);//search_key returns pointer to the node just before the node holding the key.

if(prev_node!= NULL)
{
    // prev_node->next is the one that needs to be deleted
    temp = prev_node->next; 

    //Make the prev node point to the next node of the one that's getting deleted
    prev_node->next = temp->next; 

    free(temp);
    return;
}
```

Comment: i updated the search function but forgot to update the comment. i have edited it.thanks!

Answer (score 3):

#### First bug

```
head=temp->next;
```

Since `head` is a local parameter this assignment changes this local parameter. You need to change the pointer passed to the function, so you need your code to be:

```
void delete_from_key(node **head, int key)
    //...
    *head=temp->next;
    //...
```

#### 2nd bug

```
new = new->next;
```

Kind of the same problem. `new` is a local variable. You are changing a local variable, you aren't changing the pointer within the list.

If `search_key` indeed returns pointer to the node before the found key you need

```
temp = new->next;
new->next = new->next->next;
free(temp);
```